# Optimizing lumber purchasing

Tags: optimization

**I would like to know how to classify the following optimization problem.**

A lumber yard sells 2x4's in various stock lengths. For example, an 8ft could be $3 and a 10ft could be $4, while a 14ft might be $5.50. Importantly, the lengths are not linearly related to price and not all discrete lengths can be purchased as stock. It can be assumed that the available stock units are inexhaustible in these discrete lengths.

```
length    cost
7.7ft     $2.75
  8ft     $3.00
 10ft     $4.00
 14ft     $5.50
```

I need to create a set of 2x4's with given lengths by cutting them from the above stock (say I need lengths of 2ft, 2.5ft, 6ft once all is said and done). Also, each "cut" incurs a material cost of 1/8" (i.e. 0.0104ft). The solution of the problem is an assignment of each desired length to a piece of stock with the total cost of all stock minimized. In this example, the optimal solution minimizing cost is to buy a 14ft board at $5.50. (A runner-up solution is to buy two 8ft boards and allocate as {6ft} and {2ft, 0.0104ft, 2.5ft} for a cost of $6.)

**It does not seem to be a Knapsack-class problem. It does not seem to be a cutting stock problem (because I would like to minimize cost rather than minimize waste). What sort of problem is this, and how can I go about efficiently solving it?**

(As an after-note, this is a non-fictional problem I have solved in the obvious, inefficient way using multiset partitions and iteration in Haskell. The runtime is prohibitive to practical use with more than 23 desired lengths and 6 available stock sizes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is a cutting stock problem, except that it's a multi-objective or multi-criteria cutting stock problem (where you want to minimize monetary cost as well as material cost), see for this example [this article](http://www.sbmac.org.br/eventos/cnmac/xxxiii_cnmac/pdf/140.pdf).  Unfortunately almost all of the online resources I found for this breed of cutting stock problem were behind paywalls; in addition, I haven't done any integer-linear programming in several years, but if I remember correctly multi-objective problems are much more difficult than single-objective problems.

One option is to implement a two-pass algorithm.  The first pass completely ignores the material cost of cutting the boards, and only uses the monetary cost (in place of the waste cost in a standard cutting stock problem) in a single-objective problem.  This may leave you with an invalid solution, at which point you perform a [local search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_search_%28optimization%29) to e.g. replace two 10-foot boards with a 14-foot board and an 8-foot bard until you reach a valid solution.  Once you find a valid solution, you can continue the local search for several more iterations to see if you can improve on the solution.  This algorithm will likely be sub-optimal when compared to a one-pass multi-objective solution, but it ought to be much easier to implement.

Comment: Could you provide any references to paywalled articles? I may be able to access them through my school's library.

Comment: [Study of one-dimensional cutting stock problem with multi-objective optimization](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6308918&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Ftp%3D%26arnumber%3D6308918) and [Approximation Algorithms to Solve Real-Life Multicriteria Cutting Stock Problems](http://or.journal.informs.org/content/47/4/495.abstract)